# Why does using await produce different behaviour in my debugger than by using .then?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I have two blocks of code, they're almost identical apart from one of them uses await to wait for some database operations to finish, and then second uses .then() to wait for the operations to finish.

I've noticed that while using my debugger, some unexpected behavior occurs with the await usage. Specifically, the execution will first go to the call to `insertNewTokenHolderCount()`, but then execution will immediately jump to inside of the `upsertNewIconSource()` method. After continuing the execution will jump back to outside `upsertNewIconSource()`, and then execution will continue inside `upsertNewIconSource()`.

This doesn't happen why using .then(), and the execution goes as expected; first to `insertNewTokenHolderCount` and then that finishes, and then to `upsertNewIconSource`.

Why is this happening?

I've attached a gif to better show the execution path.

#### with `await`

```js
for (const token of allTokens) {
    let url = "https://bscscan.com/token/" + token.contractAddress;
    let scrapeResults: ScrapeResults = await this.provider.BscScanService.getTokenDataFromWebsite(url);

    await this.provider.TokenHolderCountRepo.insertNewTokenHolderCount({
        tokenId: token.id,
        holderCount: scrapeResults.holderCount,
        date: Date.now()
    });

    await this.provider.TokenIconRepo.upsertNewIconSource({
        tokenId: token.id,
        iconSrc: scrapeResults.tokenIconSrc
    });
}
```

#### with `.then()`

```js
for await (const token of allTokens) {
    let url = "https://bscscan.com/token/" + token.contractAddress;
    let scrapeResults: ScrapeResults = await this.provider.BscScanService.getTokenDataFromWebsite(url);

    this.provider.TokenHolderCountRepo.insertNewTokenHolderCount({
        tokenId: token.id,
        holderCount: scrapeResults.holderCount,
        date: Date.now()
    }).then(() => {
        this.provider.TokenIconRepo.upsertNewIconSource({
            tokenId: token.id,
            iconSrc: scrapeResults.tokenIconSrc
        });
    })
}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Are you using a transpiler? Source maps?

Comment: What is `allTokens`, an array? In the second code you're using `for await … of`, which you probably shouldn't.

Comment: @jm123456, I don't think this is any kind of problem... Just don't  worry about how they are being called and how they scheduled, You have more important thing to worry about like global warming...

Comment: @Bergi The await makes no difference to the execution, it was supposed to be removed but I forgot

Comment: @Bergi The code is being executed with TS-Node, would that have an effect?

Comment: @jm123456 Certainly. TS-Node probably transpiles async/await syntax, but I don't know how to check for this. Try using the typescript compiler alone and look at the resulting code.

Comment: Why are-you `await`ing `upsertNewIconSource` in the first example while you are not `then`ing `upsertNewIconSource` in the second example? This is clearly a difference.